# Migrating from Spring security 2.0 to Spring security 3.0.7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I am having a project which uses Spring framework(migrated from 2.0 to 3.0.7) and Spring security 2.0. And I want to use Spring security 3.0.7. I have used MessageDigestPasswordEncoder, SecurityContextHolder. But now I've added Spring security 3.0.7 jar files to my project but it is showing some compilation issues to above classes.

I need help for migration.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you go to [Spring Security site](http://www.springsource.org/spring-security) you can see that they recommend the [Spring Security book](http://www.springsecuritybook.com/). The chapter 13 covers what you want to do. I have this book and it's really worth it.