# Spring security 2.0 to spring security 3.0

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm upgrading my application from `spring security 2.0` to `spring security 3.0`.

There are many changes in `spring security 3.0`.

I did some of the migration effortless but some giving trouble like custom-authentication-provider etc.

Can some share steps or details for migration.

Comment: Hi Kamahire, what you're asking is extremely broad for a Q&A site. I think this is one of those things where you just have to start digging into it yourself, and then when you get stuck in a particular spot, come back and see us and ask a more specific, targeted question, with code, stack traces, and details. I'd suggest you Google the Spring Security 3.0 site. I'm sure they have plenty of examples and documentation there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Migrating from Spring security 2.0 to Spring security 3.0.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543229/migrating-from-spring-security-2-0-to-spring-security-3-0-7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [this](http://www.packtpub.com/article/migration-to-spring-security-3) article which addresses some common migration issues?

The spring security site also recommends reading the [Spring Security Book](http://www.springsecuritybook.com/). Chapter 13, Migration to Spring Security 3 covers all the configuration changes and might have the information you are looking for.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543229/migrating-from-spring-security-2-0-to-spring-security-3-0-7) related question on SO.